# Routed Command Implementation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, commandbinding

I have simple ICommand-Bindings working, however I have Buttons inside an ItemsControl and wanted to get the sender information, like with the normal `Routed-Events (object sender, e RoutedEventArgs)` and this seems not to be possible with the normal ICommands, right?

I am a little bit lost here.

I currently use the Prism 6 DelegateCommand-Class to get things working. It looks like this:

```
private ICommand _selectCommand;
public ICommand SelectCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _selectCommand ?? (_selectCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SelectImage));
    }
}

private void SelectImage(object image)
{
    var img = (BitmapImage)image;
    var index = Scans.IndexOf(img);
    this.CurrentIndex = index + 1;
    ImageToDisplay = img;
}
```

How I can I get the RoutedCommand to work?

Comment: You could send the BitmapImage as the CommandParameter.

Comment: I am doing this, however I need to change the button associated with the element and I cannot access the ui-elements inside the viewmodel.

Comment: How do you invoke the command?

Comment: Currently like this: Command="{Binding ElementName=bindingHelper, Path=DataContext.SelectCommand}". This in itself is working.

Comment: You shouldn't change the Button directly. You change a property that the Button is bound to.

Comment: I see, this is indeed possible. Thank you. It should basically behave like a Radio, or Toogle Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view model is not supposed to be accessing or even know about any view element.

You should bind a target property of the control in the view to a source property of the view model that you can simply set in your `SelectImage` method when your command gets executed.

Comment: Yes, however I only can to this in 4 minutes, however I would usually go in one. I am staying for this.